# How to connect an Arduino with SIM300 and a seperate GPS module?

Tags: gps

I am trying to connect an Arduino with SIM300 and GPS module to upload data directly into a database on my localhost using GPRS of the SIM inserted. I am not able to interface the separate GPS and GSM modules. Kindly help in this regard.

Comment: If you give more details , that would be helpful. The amount of information you give, it looks like you need a tutorial not an answer.

Comment: I am using seperate gps and a gsm module. I am using an A6390 gsm and neo 6m gps module. i want to fetch gps data and uplaod to a local database using gprs through the gsm module

Answer (score 2):

I know I should write this in comment section , but as comment have word limitation and I'm going to give you a idea why this should not be a question and how should you go for your problem, I'm writing it in answer section.Please don't down voted me :p

You miss the point of my comment. This is a forum where you ask about your problem and people try to help you to solve it. It's not a tutorial providing forum. But from you'r question as far as I understand , you want more or less  a full tutorial about your circuit. That's why you are getting down vote.

First you should run your module individually . Here is two YouTube tutorial link for your GPS and GSM modules.

[GSM module tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-okAX7ZoGDk)

[GPS module tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bgOZLgaLa0g)

You can look for more tutorials in YouTube and build a besic idea. Then make GSM and GPS module working individually. When individually they work, then add there code and components and run the whole system. This way , it will be easy for you to detect where the problem is. If you'r device fail and you can't find or solve the problem, then ask here.

There is some rules how to ask questions here, follow them. Give total idea about your problem and how far you can debug.If possible, add your code and circuit diagram. Hope we can help you then.